# Check dropdown status

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, meteor

Is there a way to know if a dropdown is showed or not?

this is my html

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></a>
```

I want to check it for example in an event like on the modals.

```
Template.filterContainer.events({
    'show.bs.collapse' : function( event ){
        var instance = Template.instance();

        instance.vars.set( 'type-open', true );
    },

    'hide.bs.collapse' : function(){
        var instance = Template.instance();

        instance.vars.set('type-open' , false );
    }
});
```

But how i do this with the dropdown, i just cant figure out.

Comment: You can use an event, or you can detect state by observing an element's class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the answer over there so you have 2 possible solutions to this.

**Change the events**

from `show.bs.collapse` to `show.bs.dropdown`

**or change the HTML**

from `data-toggle="drop down"` to `data-toggle="collapse"`